# Please Help on database making a program to catalog

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have looked at similar questions and it doesn't look like any of them have been answered.

Suppose you are writing a functional specification to design a software application that allows users to catalogue their DVD movie collection.  The business stakeholder has the following requirements:

•   Want to be able to enter each DVDs information (movie title, actors, director, genre, release year, rating, and a brief synopsis of the movie)
•   Want to be able to look up the DVD collection by any of those attributes

How would you design this program, what would it look like?  Sketch screen shot(s) for this application.

Comment: one table with all those columns, make whever column that you need to enforce with enum a foreign key to another table..easy as that isnt it..

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by a single table having column for all your information
like

table dvdinfo
{
dvdname varchar2,
title varchar2,
etc....
}

and you can implement finder for each column.